# printing value of button when pressed React

Tags: reactjs, button

I'm new to react and I don't know some basic things so I got confused about this problem. Here's the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './css/style.css'



class Calculator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        
      }  
      
      click = ()=>{
        console.log(button.value)
        

      }
      render(){
          return(
              <div>
                  <button value='1' onClick = {this.click()}>1</button>
              </div>
          )
      }
} 
export default Calculator
```

How can I get value of button in my console? should I create button class or maybe there's more efficient method to do it?

Comment: I want to access the value which is '1' to use it in calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `click` method accept an argument, and pass `this.click` as a callback instead of invoking it immediately on load or in an anonymous wrapper function, you can reference the event target to get to the button, and from that get to the value:

```js
class Calculator extends React.Component {
      click = (e) => {
          console.log(e.target.value);
      }
      render(){
          return(
              <div>
                  <button value='1' onClick = {this.click}>1</button>
              </div>
          )
      }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```